# SAML SSO authentication flow for custom SAML connector in Jumpcloud applications

Tags: single-sign-on, single-page-application, saml, saml-2.0

we are trying [JumpCloud](https://jumpcloud.com) for the IDaaS for one of our applications and trying to configure SSO login to it with a custom SAML 2.0 connector.

We have already configured a assertion consumer service endpoint there which receives a POST response upon successfull authentication of a user. Now we are able to successfully receive the SAMLResponse there but I am not able to figure out the next steps here ? do I pass this signed / encrypted response to the webapp as is and use it for validating API requests or do I need to query jumpcloud for a token associated with this response.

The general [wikipedia article on SAML2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#Artifact_Resolution_Protocol) I read suggests that we need to query a artifact resolution service to exchange the received assertion saml response for a token to be used in client applications. But i have not found any references to this in the jumpcloud documentation.

Also, the organization user session duration settings in jumpcloud are set to 1 hour and still the expiry time in the SAMLResponse seems to be only 5 minutes after token creation, so what do I do if we need to extend this token duration because I would not want the users to login after every 5 minutes.

Can someone with experience / familiarity in JumpCloud please help / point me in the right direction here ?

Here is the sample SAMLResponse I am receiving from the IDP -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" Destination="https://ixr6rl0xpk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/saml" ID="MGAZWYVBHO9VMET0GNQAG1YILCCALLJL1QZUCTLN" IssueInstant="2019-10-24T14:38:11.414Z" Version="2.0">
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">jumpcloud</saml2:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#MGAZWYVBHO9VMET0GNQAG1YILCCALLJL1QZUCTLN">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="xs" />
                    </ds:Transform>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <ds:DigestValue>qQY2SBgD...</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>H8XemIw1nNCkq7nL...</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIIFfTCCA2W...</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="JW4VMBUW3OD8KZJXG07QHLZOLEMNEDDW93H6WPIS" IssueInstant="2019-10-24T14:38:11.414Z" Version="2.0">
        <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">jumpcloud</saml2:Issuer>
        <saml2:Subject>
            <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:nameid-format:unspecified">email@example.com</saml2:NameID>
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2019-10-24T14:43:11.414Z" Recipient="<ACS_URL>" />
            </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2019-10-24T14:33:11.414Z" NotOnOrAfter="2019-10-24T14:43:11.414Z">
            <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml2:Audience>example.com</saml2:Audience>
            </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml2:Conditions>
        <saml2:AttributeStatement>
            <saml2:Attribute Name="memberOf" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
                <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">test group</saml2:AttributeValue>
            </saml2:Attribute>
        </saml2:AttributeStatement>
        <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2019-10-24T14:38:11.414Z" SessionIndex="330dafe4-e541-4b93-85b2-2c5d76d75996">
            <saml2:AuthnContext>
                <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml2:AuthnContext>
        </saml2:AuthnStatement>
    </saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically in `SAML`, the user is asserting their right to "login" to the service. In an "old fashioned" service, they would assert that right by going to a login page at the service, typing their username and password and if they pass authentication, the service does "something" to let them in. That "something" can be anything. Setting up a cookie session or whatever. That "something" has nothing to do with `SAML`. `SAML` only transports their assertion.

In `SAML`, instead of typing a username/password, they are arriving at the service with a `SAML` `Response` that contains details of how they authenticated at their own Identity Provider (IdP) and any attributes about them.

In your `SAML` `Response` they have a single attribute:

```
<saml2:Attribute Name="memberOf" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
  <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">test group</saml2:AttributeValue>
</saml2:Attribute>
```

which says they are a `memberOf` the entity `test group`.

If the service allows access to members of test group then they can "login", i.e. they have successfully asserted their right to tell the service to do that "something" that it does for non `SAML` users.

It doesn't matter if they have an old fashioned key, a card, a fingerprint or a facial recognition. Once that part of the process has been verified, the service can use whatever mechanism it uses to open the door.

When I SAML enabled systems, I'd first look at the code for the authentication and authorisation for the service to see what the next step was (the "something" bit). Then add a new endpoint (the ACS) and plumb it into the existing "something".